# Intuition behind moments of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance, moment-generating-functions

I am looking to understand the intuition behind moments of random variables.

I understand the first moment relating to the mean and the second one relating to the variance. But what use does the n-th moment have?

Thank you

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190531/what-is-the-use-of-moments-in-statistics

Answer (score 0):

Probably you also know that the third moment the asymmetry of the distribution ([skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness)), and the fourth moment tells you how the tails are behaved ([kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis)). But perhaps you can get some insight from the moment generating function

$$
M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{tX}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_k \frac{t^k}{k!}X^k\right] = \sum_k \frac{t^k}{k!}\mathbb{E}[X^k] = \sum_k \frac{t^k}{k!}\left.\frac{{\rm d}^k M(t)}{{\rm d}t^k}\right|_{t=0}
$$

If you know all moments $\mathbb{E}[X^k]$ (or equivalently $M_X(t)$) you could try to invert the problem and actually estimate the underlaying PDF, this is know as the [moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem)